# don't show checkbox type boolean on models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

## i have models item filed itm_stop:

```
class item(models.Model):
  itm_stop=models.BooleanField(verbose_name='item stop',default=False)
```

in file forms.py:

```
from django import forms,modelsForm
class itemsForm(modelsForm.Form):

    class Meta:
        model =item
        fields = "__all__"
```

in file views.py :

```
from .forms import itemsForm
def items_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = itemsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    else:
        form = itemsForm()
    return render(request, 'items/items.html',{"items" :form})
```

in file Templates item.html:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% for field in items %}
<!-- append to an attribute -->

<div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
    <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
    {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

When I do the presentation, I cannot display the checkbox, and it appears as an empty box on the page, and I did not find the reason for that

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this I would just subclass the forms class instead of modelForm class

So in your forms you would use forms.BooleanField like this ...

```
from django import forms

class itemsForm(forms.Form):
    itm_stop= forms.BooleanField(
        label='item stop',
        initial=False
    )
```

Here is how you access them:
You don't need to do for field in items

```
<div class="form-group">
   {% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}
    <label for="{{ items.itm_stop}} ">{{items.itm_stop.label}}</label>
    {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: I have added what you need in your template to make it work

Comment: what is need add in template

Comment: Ive updated my answer. You can try it but Im not sure it will work because I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do in your template. Can you update your question explaining when you want the check box to show up and if there is any other code in your views or template that would help. It also looks like you have an extra {% endfor %} with no opening {% for %}

Comment: The main problem facing the problem of the emergence of a problem appearing only and for {% for%} from the emergence of an error upon implementation, thank you